1.5 year old boy, doesn't seem fully connected socially, compared to his social butterfly outgoing twin brother
I have been worried that my 1.5 year old son is possibly on the autism spectrum. He is. twin so unfortunately I do compare the two. However, it is usually a one way compare, why is he not acting or doing what his brother is?
My son is very laid back, he does have bursts of energy like any kid but most of the time seems in a great mood, happy and content with anything going on.  He is verbal and can talk in nearly full sentences, his short sentences are great and spoken correctly although sometimes long sentences/conversations he tries to have could be labeled as gibberish, but it does make sense and is almost always appropriate to the situation. If that makes sense? He can essentially ask for example ( He wonders about his papa tractor and its horn and likes to tell me that its at his papas house) He will say something like " Papas beep beep (tractor) gibberish gibberish at home, papa at home? beep beep. " He will tell you this with great concern for where his papas tractor is at. He when he asks questions gibberish added or not he will have it backed with the correct emotion. "where's sissy?" he will hold his hands out and look at you for an answer. He is hard to make consistent eye contact with, he will some of the time but it is not held long. He has no problem continuing the interaction without eye contact. This has been the ultimate RED FLAG for me, this is what initiated our visit to the peds. He is being seen my Early On, but I they are not assessing him other than once a month visit where they come play with him.
He knows so many words, he knows how most things work. He can work the TV, when the next episode needs to be selected. He doesn't seem to have any sensory issues, if anyone has issues with sensory it's his twin brother, that boy cant stand pants or long sleeve shirts.
There's just something about him that seems off to me, tonight we went to the fair. His brother was so excited for the animals, saying bye bye to them by name, saying hi. Telling his "Nana horse" where his brother in question had no interest in interacting with the animals. He doesn't say hi to strangers like his sister and brother do. Tonight he took a lot of coaxing to get involved and engaged and it honestly broke my heart to see him just not care interact with us, unless we were trying extremely hard, like having to tickle him to get him to become involved. He honestly just loves to walk and wanted nothing but to walk and run around which made him upset multiple times.
He does play with his brother and sister, they parallel play and play together. He will present to sleep and snore, he had a stuff animal cat the other day and was pretending it was running alone the couch and floor meowing the entire time. He will hug the stuff animals and mimic the things they should do. He will copy our dogs and things we say. He will interact with Mickey Mouse clubhouse, sing the theme song and look to you at certain parts because those are his fav. He will follow directions and complete tasks with effort on our part but what 1.5 year old doesn't need help completing tasks asked of them like throwing their dirty diapers away in kitchen garbage that is located in a cabinet that they have to open.
I just cant let it do, he isn't as animated as his siblings. Hes just different from them. I totally know no two children are the same but has anyone else had a child that just constantly teetered on being autistic or not?

Welcome! Can you please clarify: what exactly is your question? Note that this is a Q/A site, not a forum, so we need a clear question, that then can be answered by the community. We will also not give medical advice, particularly not for a specific person. I recommend you invest a bit of time and take the [tour], and to browse the [help], particularly [ask].

If you are really worried, go see a doctor. But probably nothing... Kids change a lot in the first years... i got a little cousin who was shy and laid back and is now the wild one of her siblings.

@stephie The question is the very last sentence of the post, im not sure how you didn't catch that? I am simply ASKING (because "asking" is a question, hence the "......has anyone else had a child that just constantly teetered on being autistic or not?" ) if anyone has had a similar situation in their children. Im sorry my post prompted you to feel the need to post what you did. You also do not know that my child is being seen under medical advice. So I greatly appreciate you.

@RandiO'Dowd please note that I am giving you guidance in my role as a moderator of the site. I understand that worrying about our children can be tough, nevertheless there are rules that apply to all Stack Exchange sites. One of them is the clear question - and your last sentence strictly speaking can be answered with “yes” or “no” (and I guess neither would be helpful for you), which is what prompted my comment: What do you really need? I also noted that you mentioned your paediatrician, but we get a lot of new users seeking medical advice, which is off topic here. Just trying to help.

"why is he not acting or doing what his brother is?" No one here can answer that. Kids don't teeter on being autistic; they are or are not somewhere on the spectrum. We do have users here with kids on the autism spectrum, and a number of users on the spectrum themselves. If you search the site using the autism tag, you'll have lots of info from the questions and answers these folks posted. Your child is now of the age where testing should be done for autism. That's what needs to be done (by an experienced professional); if the doctor/tester is unsure, your child will be tested again.

I’m closing this question because it currently just asks if anyone has had a child on the edge of autism - this is opinion-based and not useful to future visitors. If you can edit the post to meet our site requirements (see our [ask] and [about] pages) we can re-open.

It sounds to me like one child is different then his twin, but that's not a problem.  He is contented, likes pretend play, and may possible have some slight introverted tendencies.  He's different, but he's still fine.
I doubt it's autism:
First let me say that autism is not diagnosed until at least age 3, so there is no way to say much about them having autism at such a young age.  In fact it's quite common for there to be absolutely no sign of autism at all until 18-24 months old, so depending on how you are rounding when you say the twins are 1.5 years old it's possible your son is young enough still that one wouldn't expect any autistic signs even if he were autistic.
Signs of autism at that age would include such things as:

avoiding or not making eye contact
not follow moving objects with eyes
inability to walk (or walks only on toes)
no words or limited talking
rocking back and forth or similar stimming activities when upset
lack of smiling, laughing, or babbling
Does not use hand gestures like waving or pointing.
lack of pretend play

Not only did you not describe any of this you described examples of the opposite, including extensive vocabulary, lots of pretend play, implied ability to walk and gesture, and presumably laughter if he enjoys being tickled. None of what you described sounds like Autism.
You mentioned eye contact which you think is a problem, but the way you describe it doesn't sound autistic to me.  People with autism are unlikely to make eye contact at all unless/until they are 'taught' to do it to fit in better, but you said your son does make eye contact, he simply doesn't maintain it.  Given his age this is likely a result of attention span and an inability to sit and focus on anything for a long time.  Since he is at least initiating eye contact I wouldn't consider it an indicator of autism.
Of course since autism signs wouldn't necessarily be evident at such a young age that doesn't prove he definitely isn't autistic, but I would put his odds at no higher, perhaps even lower, then that of any random child, ie roughly 1/54
Kids are different
You said he is less animated and more content.  It's likely he simply prefers to observe the world more then directly interact with it.  That's actually pretty common with more naturally contented kids, because their content with things the way it is they don't need to be as active to entertain themselves because their already enjoying things as it is.  Part of the reason he has such an impressive grasp on language may be because he's spending more time listening to you and learning it while his peer is busy with more physical play
He seems to like pretend play more then physical games as well from what you describe, again that just means he likes to interact with the world in a different manner,  There is nothing inherently better of worse with pretend play over more physical play.
Finally he might be introverted, it's hard to say from what you described.  However it would fit with his not choosing to engage in some of your games, such as with visiting animals, and his seeming less animated and more prone to self play.  If he is introverted that's not a problem either 1/4 people are introverts after all.
Also he may just not like, or be afraid of, larger animals like horses, which is fine too ;)
What you're child needs need from you
Kids will be different, with different interests, ways to approach the world, and desires.  What they need is a caregiver that can understand that and support their needs.  It's not good to try to force a child into a box and make them fit your mold of what a child should be, they need to be encouraged to be themselves.
That means as natural as it may be at times you should try to stop comparing the twins.  They can be different people with different interests. In particular you never ever want to imply to your son that you think there is something wrong with his not enjoying the things his twin enjoys.  Don't make him think he's expected to live up to someone else or that you have favorites.
Instead it's best to figure out what his interests and desires are and find ways to engage him in these areas he is most interested in.  He doesn't want to play with animals, okay then he doesn't have to.  Maybe he wants to talk with you, or play with his stuffed animals, or even go by himself and do his own thing at times.  He doesn't have to like all the things his peers like.  You should make that clear and find the things he likes ensuring he gets chances to do those things with you as well.
In short let him be himself, enjoy what he enjoys, and know that his parent(s) love him like that and will encourage him to be the way he is.

That you doubt it's autism is irrelevant. If you're going to make a diagnosis (you just did; a negative is still diagnosing), you need more proof that what you are saying is recognized by reliable sources to be correct (it's not. Just for the record.) It's just not possible to be unconcerned about such remarkable differences, so your admonitions aren't helpful. If the child actually is on the spectrum, they're actively harmful. You seem to be unaware that autism exists on a spectrum. You treat it like one disorder. It's not.

Please don’t attempt to diagnose a child via the Internet based on a few lines of parental description. The part about how to support each child based on their personal needs is fine (and actually quite helpful in my opinion), but stay away from medical advice.
